# ARM template for classic alert to new alert conversion

Tags: azure, alert

I have created 1 web test classic alert through the Azure Portal. Now I want to convert the classic alert to the new alert .I am using the following ARM template for the same.

```
{
    "name": "TestMetricAlert",
    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts",
    "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
    "location": "global",
    "tags": {},
    "properties": {
      "description": "Test Metric Description",
      "severity": 2,
      "enabled": true,
      "scopes": [

      ],
      "evaluationFrequency": "PT5M",
      "windowSize": "PT5M",
      "targetResourceType": "Microsoft.Insights/webtests",
      "targetResourceRegion": "eastus",
      "criteria": {
        "additionalProperties": {},
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "/subscriptions/a85f72bb-4bc4-4a9a-b77b-83db1cc0e1e4/resourceGroups/TestProjectRG/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/testalert-testappinsights"
      ],
      "autoMitigate": false,
      "actions": [
        {
          "actionGroupId": "/subscriptions/a85f72bb-4bc4-4a9a-b77b-83db1cc0e1e4/resourceGroups/TestProjectRG/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/TestAction"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But during deployment I am getting the following error.

> Template deployment returned the following errors:
>   11:56:16 - 11:56:15 AM - Resource Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts 'TestMetricAlert' failed with message '{
>   11:56:16 -   "Code": "BadRequest",
>   11:56:16 -   "Message": "No object created."
>   11:56:16 - }'

Could someone help me in rectifying what is wrong here or anything needs to be changed in the ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

Other than trying the [Migration tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-using-migration-tool) from the Azure portal, you could also refer to the sample template mentioned in [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-create-templates#template-for-a-simple-static-threshold-metric-alert) doc, or even export the template from the Azure portal to check the representation. The following template works for me:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name": {
        "defaultValue": "test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "webtests_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "components_test_log_analytics_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/components/test-log-analytics",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/metricalerts",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name')]",
        "location": "global",
        "tags": {
            "hidden-link:/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/components/test-log-analytics": "Resource",
            "hidden-link:/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/alertrg/providers/microsoft.insights/webtests/test-new-alerts-test-log-analytics": "Resource"
        },
        "properties": {
            "description": "[concat('Automatically created alert rule for availability test \"', parameters('metricalerts_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_name'), '\"')]",
            "severity": 1,
            "enabled": true,
            "scopes": [
                "[parameters('webtests_test_new_alerts_test_log_analytics_externalid')]",
                "[parameters('components_test_log_analytics_externalid')]"
            ],
            "evaluationFrequency": "PT1M",
            "windowSize": "PT5M",
            "criteria": {
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.WebtestLocationAvailabilityCriteria"
            },
            "actions": []
        }
    }
]
}
```

Hope this helps!

**Note:** The retirement date for classic alerts migration has been extended to August 31st, 2019 from the originally announced date of June 30th, 2019.